# Add button to an expandablelistview

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, button, expandablelistview

I have a created an expandablelistview in an android fitness app, when an exercises is pressed on, an image of the exercise and description in displayed, however I would like to add a button underneath each image.
How can this be done?

.java code

```
    package com.example.myfitnessbuddy;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

    public class ChestActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
    {
    private ExpandListAdapter ExpAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Group> ExpListItems;
    private ExpandableListView ExpandList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chest);

        ExpandList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expList);
        ExpListItems = SetStandardGroups();
        ExpAdapter = new ExpandListAdapter(ChestActivity.this, ExpListItems);
        ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chest, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public ArrayList<Group> SetStandardGroups() {

        String[] input_names = {"Bench Press (Bands)","Bench Press      (Barbell)","Bench Press Close Grip (Barbell)"
                ,"Bench Press (Dumbbell)","Bench Press (Machine)","Bent Over     Crossover"
                ,"Decline Chest Press (Machine)","Fly (Cable)","Fly (Dumbbell)"
                ,"Incline Chest Press (Dumbbell)","Pec Deck","Push-up"
                ,"Push-up Elevated Feet"};
        String[] info_sections = {"Primary Type: Chest /n Muscle(s) worked: pectoralis, triceps brachii, deltoids"
                ,"Primary Type: Chest /n Muscle(s) worked: pectoralis, triceps brachii, deltoids"
                ,"Primary Type: Chest /n Muscle(s) worked: pectoralis, triceps brachii, deltoids"
                ,"Primary Type: Chest /n Muscle(s) worked: pectoralis, triceps brachii, deltoids"
                ,"Primary Type: Chest /n Muscle(s) worked: pectoralis, triceps brachii, deltoids"
                ,"Primary Type: Chest /n Muscle(s) worked: pectoralis, deltoids"
                ,"Primary Type: Chest /n Muscle(s) worked: pectoralis, triceps brachii, deltoids"
                ,"Primary Type: Chest /n Muscle(s) worked: pectoralis"
                ,"Primary Type: Chest /n Muscle(s) worked: pectoralis"
                ,"Primary Type: Chest /n Muscle(s) worked: pectoralis, triceps brachii"
                ,"Primary Type: Chest /n Muscle(s) worked: pectoralis"
                ,"Primary Type: Chest /n Muscle(s) worked: pectoralis, triceps brachii"
                ,"Primary Type: Chest /n Muscle(s) worked: pectoralis, triceps brachii, deltoids"};
        int previews[] = {R.drawable.bench_press_bands,R.drawable.bench_press_barbell,R.drawable.bench_press_close_grip
                ,R.drawable.bench_press_dumbbell,R.drawable.bench_press_machine,R.drawable.bent_over_crossover
                ,R.drawable.decline_chest_press_machine,R.drawable.fly_cable,R.drawable.fly_dumbbell
                ,R.drawable.incline_chest_press_dumbbell,R.drawable.pec_deck,R.drawable.push_up
                ,R.drawable.push_up_elevated_feet};

        ArrayList<Group> list = new ArrayList<Group>();
        ArrayList<Child> child_list;
        int a=0;

        for(String input_name:input_names)
        {
            Group input = new Group();
            input.setName(input_name);

            child_list = new ArrayList<Child>();
            Child child = new Child();
            child.setName(info_sections[a]);
            child.setImage(previews[a]);
            child_list.add(child);

            input.setItems(child_list);
            list.add(input);
            a++;
        }

        return list;
    }

    public void selectExercise(View view)
    {
        /*Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExerciseActivity.class);

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case (R.id.basics_ui):
                intent = new Intent(this, BasicsUIActivity.class);
                break;
            case (R.id.basics_input):
                intent = new Intent(this, BasicsInputActivity.class);
                break;
            default:
                intent = new Intent(this, ExerciseActivity.class);
                break;
        }
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);*/
    }
}

.xml file
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/chest"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#333"
        android:textColor="#eee"/>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expList"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show us what You have done until now. I suspect You have made a custom expandableListView? Then please show relevant xml and java files..

Comment: I have updated it now to show the code for one of the expandablelistviews pages I've created